# How do I show the device location with the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, arcgis

How can get my location to display on the map using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android? Here is what I've tried:

```
mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
mMapView.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(Object o, STATUS status) {
        if (o == mMap && status == STATUS.INITIALIZED) {
            LocationDisplayManager ldm = mMap.getLocationDisplayManager();
            ldm.setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplayManager.AutoPanMode.LOCATION);
            ldm.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't use == between objects. use the o.equals(mMap)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app requests the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission by adding the following tag as a child of the `<manifest>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

(While you're there, you might want to add tags for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `INTERNET`, since most ArcGIS Runtime apps will use those too. See [the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/install-and-set-up.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C9913E8160D74241977115BEA470E1C3) for details.)

Also, make sure location is enabled on your Android device.